# ¿Cómo hacer una martiz serpentina?

Tags: java

Soy nuevo usando java y me pidieron hacer una matriz serpentina donde de entrada pida lo siguiente

Entrada:
4 5

Salida:

```
1  2  3  4  5                      
10  9  8  7  6                      
11 12 13 14 15                       
20 19 18 17 16
```

El codigo que yo hice es el siguiente:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
         int n = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
         int m = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
         int matriz[][];
        matriz = new int [n][m];
  
        int x = n*m;
         for(int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++){
            for(int j =matriz[0].length -1; j >=0; j--){
            matriz [i][j]= x;
            x--;
        }}
             for(int i =0; i< matriz.length; i++){
                  for(int j =0; j< matriz[0].length; j++){
                      System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"  ");
                  }
                  System.out.println();
             }}}
```

Al ejecutar mi codigo queda de la siguiente manera

```
16  17  18  19  20  
11  12  13  14  15  
6  7  8  9  10  
1  2  3  4  5
```

y no logro hacer que quede como el ejercio lo pide

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Gracias por compartir tu código. Ahora bien, ¿cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Deja edito la publicacion porque no entiendo como usar la pagina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que determinar si la fila empieza por numero par o impar para determinar en que dirección quieres mostrarlo:

```
//Mostrar matriz de izquierda a derecha

if (i % 2 == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++)
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
}else{

 //Mostrar matriz de izquierda a derecha

    for (int j = matriz[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
}
```

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int matriz[][] = new int[][] { 
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }, 
            { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }, 
            { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
            { 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 }
        };

        serpentine(matriz);
    }

    private static void serpentine(int[][] matriz) {

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            // si la fila es par, mostramos de izquierda a derecha
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++)
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            // Si la fila es impar, mostramos de deracha a izquierda
            } else {
                for (int j = matriz[0].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 2 3 4 5 
10 9 8 7 6 
11 12 13 14 15 
20 19 18 17 16
```

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente solución simplemente calcula el valor que debería ir en la posición *(i,j)*.

La observación clave es darse cuenta que la dirección en la que se asignan los valores de la matriz se alterna (Izquierda a Derecha -> Derecha a Izquierda -> Izquierda a Derecha ...).

Por lo que podemos usar la paridad de la fila para determinar el valor de cierta celda.

```
    // Número de filas
    int n = 4;
    // Número de columnas
    int m = 5;
    
    // Matriz de nxm
    int a[][] = new int[n][m];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            
            // i * m corresponde a los valores que preceden a esta fila

            int p = i * m;
            
            // Si el índice de la fila es par, entonces los números van de izquierda a derecha
            
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                // Luego añadimos la columna en la que estemos + 1
                a[i][j] = p + (j + 1);
            } else {
                // Si el índice de la fila es impar, entonces los números van de derecha a izquierda
                
                // Luego añadimos la diferencia entre la cantidad de columnas y la columna actual
                a[i][j] = p + (m - j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Una forma de visualizarlo es:

```
0,0    0,1    0,2    0,3
1,0    1,1    1,2    1,3
2,0    2,1    2,2    2,3
3,0    3,1    3,2    3,3
```

Para determinar el valor que va en la posición *(2,1)*, simplemente sabemos que la fila se rellenará de izquierda a derecha, por lo que el primer valor de la fila tendrá el valor 9.  Que corresponde a 2 * 4 + 1. (fila_actual * columnas) + columna_actual + 1. Notar que las filas y columnas se cuentan desde cero. Entonces la posición *(2, 1)* se encuentra una posición más allá. Por lo que tendrá el valor 10.

Comment: Gracias por ayuda, se agradece mucho que me iluminen en esto c: